# Router crashes if download speed goes to high

Tags: windows-7, router, dns, internet

If I cap my download speed to 1.5 mb/s or 2 mb/s my internet is stable however if I set the download speed cap to unlimited or 3+ mb/s it looks like my router crashes and my internet stops. During these 'crashes' I can't reach my router. Is my router broken or could this be a settings problem?

Here some more information abou the 'crashes'. The crashes happens almost instantly when Steam downloads starts and arent limited to the 1.5 mb/s. During a crash I can't reach my router's html interface, and also the wifi does not work. At the moment it looks like torrents does not cause the same problem.

The problem solves itselfs and the router works again for 1~5 min, than it crashes again. The router in qeustion is a Sitecom 300n X2

Comment: Impossible to tell with the tiny amount of information you have provided.

Comment: Do you have any clues where to look for hint? or any hints for troubleshooting. I simply don't know where to start with this problem.

Comment: Please describe the router crash in more detail: you lose the internet, but does the local network / WiFi keep running? Can you get into the router's HTML interface? Does it support `telnet`, and does this still work? What do its LEDs show when it crashes? Have you checked the manufacturer's support site to see if there is a firmware upgrade? Is there any relevant information in a knowledge base / support forum? How do you recover? Have you checked for any known problems with your ISP? Please edit your question to include this information and any other data which you think may be relevant.

Comment: It depends, what is your ISP offering you? What are you paying for. My router goes up to 300MB/S, but I think the setting is at 30 right now because that's what I'm paying for with my ISP. Also "bandwidth management", and what is the bandwidth doing (TV, downloads, streaming to TV, uploads, etc).

Comment: Also, what make and model router and applications are in use.   (I would guess the problem is with P2P making a lot of connections and either nailing the CPU on the router due to the number of packets per second or killing the connection tracking table.

Comment: I added some information and hopes this makes my problem a bit more understandable. It's not a throttling problem, it looks like the router just crashes. Important could be i recently moved and before the moving the router did not have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, assuming you've correctly isolated this problem to your router, it sounds like a really crappy buggy router. Regardless of settings, it shouldn't do this. Make sure you have the most recent firmware on it. If the most recent firmware still has the problem, look into putting an open source firmware distro on it, such as Tomato, DD-WRT, OpenWrt, Gargoyle, etc.